Floor Rot in room near bathroom
While doing install of LVP we noticed a portion of the floor was moist and the plywood on the floor rotted for approximately 7 sqft. We assume it came from water leaking from the bathroom parallel to the room. We fixed the bathroom issue, but what are the chances that could be the culprit? How can I confirm how the wood got rotten?

Water flows down hill.  Most floors are not perfectly level, so a slight/tiny slope from the bathroom would be enough, especially if the floor has a slight dip there where water can collect.  Rot does like moisture, so if no other plumbing/roof leaks, bathroom is the prime suspect.

Thanks, are house is built on a slope and definitely not leveled perfectly. What would be the best way to resolve this. Should I replace the wood or subfloor before putting the LVP tiles? It may be safer to replace it, but I am not sure if I am being overdramatic  about it. We did noticed mold prior to doing the LVP install months ago.

FWIW I have had water in a room adjacent to a bathroom that came from the bathroom's toilet (leaking when flushing) once...I'd say dry it out, see if it comes back or not...

We seemed to fix the bathroom issue ... what do you mean by seemed? ... did you fix it or didn't you fix it?

Yes, during our bathroom renovation, when we removed the old tub, there was a pipe that was leaking underneath and overtime rotted the wood in several areas. My contractor installed new piping and new wood in the bathroom that had rotted.

@SJN, I edited your question to state the bath issue was fixed.

Wood in homes generally only rots from moisture.  There's no way to say for certain whether it was the bathroom except to monitor it.  To answer your question in the comments (which really should be a separate question) about whether you should replace the wood/subfloor before installing LVP: yes.
